# airtime cost / Net access message in j2me while calling webservice

Tags: java-me, midp, signing, jsr172

I have a j2me application with midp 1.0

It works completely in other devices like Nokia n8, Nokia 5233 but when I test this application on Sony Ericsson Aspen it's giving me warning message like

```
Untrusted application
  your application wants to send or receive information from
  http://myurl/getLaunchDateByDate.php?Launch_date=2012-04-27,
  this will use airtime which may cost you money.
  Do you allow Net access?
```

Is it related to application signing?